# Distribution of Cumulative Heads in a Coin Flip Game

Tags: probability

So we are playing a game of coin flips. I want to know what the distribution of the number heads in a game of $n$ flips. Using some basic-back of the envelope calculations the probability of getting $m$ heads in a game with $n$ flips should be,
$$P(x=m)=\binom{n}{m}/2^n $$

My problem: I ran a simulation of 200 coin flips, and I ran this simulation 1000 times.
The distribution looked nothing like the one predicted by the equation above. My question is why?
Since the expected value of each simulation should be 100 heads (since I flip 200 times), running this simulation 1000 times and then summing the number of heads, the distribution of the number of heads across 1000 simulation should be very centered, with a very small standard deviation than the theoretical distribution above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is some error in your simulation.  As you have $200,000$ flips, the standard deviation in the total should be about $\frac 12\sqrt{200,000}\approx 223.6$.  Most likely your random number generator is biased.

Comment: It is difficult to say where the error lies since we don't know how you conducted your simulation, but we can at least tell you that the expression you obtained for the probability of $m$ heads in $n$ flips of a **fair** coin is correct.

Comment: I used excel. This is the function I used. =if(rand()<.5,1,0). I am 100% confident it has nothing to do with the number generation.

Comment: So what did you get for the average number of heads per run and the standard deviation of the number?